# Display date of last refresh from OLEDB

Tags: excel, vba

I've got an excel doc that refreshes data into a pivot from an external source. How would I go about displaying the last refresh data in a cell on the sheet?

Comment: When the you do the refresh simply put the date into a cell on the sheet?

Comment: yeah, that is exactly what I'd like to do. So users can see the last time the data was updated.

Comment: LOL.  I get what Taelsin is suggesting.  If you're refreshing the data using VBA, then why not simply use VBA to set the refresh date in a cell on your sheet.  I'm guessing you're using the Refresh All button (or something like that) and not your own VBA code to refresh the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have control over the external source, or over the query that retrieves the data from the external source, then you might be able to include a column with the current datetime.  E.g., in T-SQL you would add a field like `getdate() AS [refreshDate]`.

Then you would reference that new field using an Excel formula.  For example, if you're using the Excel Power Pivot Data Model you could use something like this:

```
="Last Refresh Date:  " & TEXT(CUBEVALUE("ThisWorkbookDataModel","[Measures].[refreshDate]"), "mm/dd/yyyy")
```

Or if your data ends up on its own sheet:

```
="Last Refresh Date:  " & Text(DataSheet!A2, "mm/dd/yyyy")
```